# Printing image from database string in PHP

Tags: php, image, variables

`$banner is a variable, which includes a string that I get it from a database. When I use $banner directly as in:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,<?php echo $banner; ?>" />
```

the string from $banner is printed on the screen instead of the image. However, if I manually copy this printed string to a new variable, i.e. $var = "Ih1ubbw........" and I use that manual variable in the code:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,<?php echo $var; ?>" />
```

the image is printed.

What is the difference between directly using $banner and copying the echoed data from $banner into another variable for use?

Comment: You should be using a MIME type of `image/jpeg` for a JPEG - not `image/png`.

Comment: May we see the code where you set `$banner` so we understand exactly how you are pulling this string from the database?

Comment: Actually I'm not getting from database. I am getting from xml-rpc server.
$request = xmlrpc_encode_request("confluence2.getAttachmentData", array($token,$pageId,'banner.png','0'));
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array(
      'method' => "POST",
      'header' => "Content-Type: text/xml",
      'content' => $request
  )));
$banner = file_get_contents("http://localhost:8090/rpc/xmlrpc", false, $context);
return $banner;

Comment: I've had issues with XML before - sometimes something you think is just a string, is actually an array node with a string stored in it. Try casting it to string before you print (i.e. `echo (string) $banner`)

Comment: I tried casting string but it didn't work. I also think it's not a basic string but I don't know how can I convert it to string.

Comment: var_dump all variables in question to see type

Comment: var_dump prints string(7476)